# Navigation Drawer and Bottom Navigation menu category dependency - Navigation Architecture Component

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have am trying to use Navigation drawer with Bottom nav, each view having its own set of menu resource.

However I am seeing a weird behavior with `back button` when `Settings` fragment is launched from nav drawer and I am on my second tab (`Account`) tab in the bottom nav.

See below :

[image]
[image]
[image]

Pressing `back or up` button on `Settings` fragment, brings me back to `Home` fragment, instead of bringing back to `Account` tab. 
**Why is that so ?**

One thing I noticed is if I provide 
`android:menuCategory="secondary"` to the `Settings` menu, this back flow works correctly and I am brought back to the `Account` tab.

I was not able to find much documentation on why this is the case and if someone can shed some more light on what should be the correct fix should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specifically called out in the [`onNavDestinationSelected` JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)):

> By default, the back stack will be popped back to the navigation graph's start destination. Menu items that have `android:menuCategory="secondary"` will not pop the back stack.